# c# best way to assemble multiple list<derived class>s' elements to sole list<base class>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types, downcast

i'm trying to make data container class which has multiple list,
i want to make property that offers gather these list's elements to one list

should i just code **GatherAllCards()** like below or are there any good way to compress the code.

classes named **card*** is derived class of **Card**

```
public class CardContainer : MonoSingleon<CardContainer>
{
    [SerializeField]
    private List<CardUnit> cardUnits;
    [SerializeField]
    private List<CardPlayerUnit> cardPlayerUnits;
    [SerializeField]
    private List<CardConsumable> cardConsumables;
    [SerializeField]
    private List<CardWeapon> cardWeapons;
    [SerializeField]
    private List<Card> cardBases;

    public IReadOnlyList<Card> AllCard
    {
        private set;
        get;
    }

    private void GatherAllCards()
    {
        List<Card> cardList = new List<Card>(500);

        foreach (var card in cardUnits)
            cardList.Add(card);
        foreach (var card in cardPlayerUnits)
            cardList.Add(card);
        foreach (var card in cardConsumables)
            cardList.Add(card);
        foreach (var card in cardWeapons)
            cardList.Add(card);
        foreach (var card in cardBases)
            cardList.Add(card);

        AllCard = cardList.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-5.0), which takes an `IEnumerable<Card>`. `IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), so passing it a `List<SpecificTypeOfCard>` is fine.

```
cardList.AddRange(cardUnits);
cardList.AddRange(cardPlayerUnits);
cardList.AddRange(cardConsumables);
cardList.AddRange(cardWeapons);
cardList.AddRange(cardBases);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or another way is `Concat`, you will just need to cast to `Card` first

> Concatenates two sequences.

```
AllCard = cardUnits
  .Cast<Card>()
  .Concat(cardPlayerUnits)
  .Concat(cardConsumables)
  .Concat(cardWeapons)
  .Concat(cardBases)
  .ToList();
```

or

```
AllCard = new List<Card>()
  .Concat(cardUnits)
  .Concat(cardPlayerUnits)
  .Concat(cardConsumables)
  .Concat(cardWeapons)
  .Concat(cardBases)
  .ToList();
```

You could also use `Union` however it does have subtle differences